# Changing the image inside of a DIV onclick of another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, it has been a while since I've had to do anything jquery and I'm having trouble recalling the simplest of tasks.

I have a **DIV** with a default image in it and I want that to change that image when I click an LI link on the page.

My question is, what does my jquery look like if I want to click 'view brown' and have it replace the default '**lboard-black**' image and so forth.

All I've really accomplished in trying to remember the syntax is show hide and toggling; Its similar to an image gallery type script I guess but much much simpler.

```
<style>
.lactive{display:block;}
</style>
```

**Image Container:**

```
<div id="StuffandThings">
<div id="lboard-black" style="display:none;" class="lactive"><img src="" /></div>
<div id="lboard-brown" style="display:none;"><img src="" /></div>
<div id="lboard-grey" style="display:none;"><img src="" /></div>
</div>
```

**Link Container:**

```
<ul>
<li><div class="lblack">view black</div></li>
<li><div class="lbrown">view brown</div></li>
<li><div class="lgrey">view grey</div></li>
</ul>
```

This is what i tried working with initially:
http://jsfiddle.net/wsfy5uo2/

Comment: "My question is, what does my jquery look like if i want to click 'view brown' and have it replace the default 'lboard-black' image and so forth" - please post what you have already tried out

Comment: its quite easy to do it, but Im not sure giving you the code is the right way for you to actual learn.

Comment: sorry, updated with jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery click method would do. https://api.jquery.com/click/
Going by your code
Something similar to the following might work, but you may consider using element IDs instead

```
$(".lblack").click(function(){
$("#StuffandThings div").hide();
$("#lboard-black").show();
});
$(".lbrown").click(function(){
$("#StuffandThings div").hide();
$("#lboard-brown").show();
});
$(".lgrey").click(function(){
$("#StuffandThings div").hide();
$("#lboard-grey").show();
});
```

See the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldtosmnx/

Update:
There are some problems with your fiddle

- You've passed .link instead of .lboard-link as the selector
- You haven't assigned any IDs to your elements in the first place

See this fiddle for corrections http://jsfiddle.net/kw1rgv23/

Comment: `$("#StuffandThings div").hide(); $("#lboard-black").show();` (and all other) could be simplified to `$("#StuffandThings div, #lboard-black").toggle();` and code will be simple and more logical ... in case this make sense

Comment: this is the simplest fix. basically was i was trying to accomplish. how can i make the black default though and change when others are clicked?

Comment: One way to do it using CSS would be to explicitly state display property for the "black" by using it's ID #lboard-black {display:block; }. Another one would be by using Jquery by simply using $("#lboard-black").show() on document load but your element won't be visible until the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event was on wrong class. It should be `.lboard-link` not `.link`. And also use `this` instead of `e.target` to get the `data-foil` instead of `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.lboard-link').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('foil').toLowerCase();
        $('.lboard-hide').hide();
        console.log(id);
        $('#' + id  + '-lboard').show();
    }); 
});
```

```css
.lboard-hide:not(:first-child){display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stuffandthings">
<div id="black-lboard" class="lboard-hide">1111</div>
<div id="brown-lboard" class="lboard-hide">2222</div>
<div id="grey-lboard" class="lboard-hide">3333</div>
</div>


<ul>
<li><div data-foil="Black" style="background-color: #000000;" class="lboard-link"> </div></li>
<li><div data-foil="Brown" style="background-color: #8B4513;" class="lboard-link"> </div></li>
<li><div data-foil="Grey" style="background-color: #cccccc;" class="lboard-link"> </div></li>
</ul>
```

You can also test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/bajreu7n/).